# Manually setting the Capybara javascript_driver results in method stubs being ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, rspec-rails

I am writing some accessibility tests for my rails app using `axe-core` which requires the use of a `javascript_driver`.

I have created a separate profile to run my accessibility tests which uses the `@accessibility` tag and I want this tag to act in the same way as adding the `@javascript` tag.

I have created a hook, shown below, which I have taken from the [Capybara gem](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/5e51607fde5e47c0e91cacf5b7c9a45d3efcfb1a/lib/capybara/cucumber.rb#L18).

```
Before('@accessibility') do
  Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver
end
```

When I then run the tests it does run using the `javascript_driver` as expected, however method stubs I have added, in this case to allow logging in, **no longer work**. If I just use the `@javascript` in addition to my own `@accessibility` tag then this does not happen.

I am running these test in the rails test environment. If there is any other information I could add that would be helpful, please let me know.